# How to kill an app with the hard buttons in Android Smartphone?

Tags: android, process

In iOS device, we can kill a foreground app with the hard buttons.  We can do it by the way written below:
1. Push down the power button and keep pushing
2. Wait for the power-off screen is shown
3. Push the Home button and keep pushing.

If we use this way, the data of the foreground app that is not saved will go away.

Usuually we only use this method when our device freezed, but some game players around me use it for other purpose.
But I dont know the same method in Android.
Do you know the method to kill the foreground app with the hard button, and without running onPause()?
If you know, could you tell me it?
*I am a (private) junior high school student in Japan.  I think I am better at using English than public school students, but there may be some grammer mistakes, wrong collocation, or spelling mistakes. So please read carefully.

Any answers or hints will be thanked.

I'm waiting for your good answers or hints!

Comment: `onDestroy();` once someone exits the app? Or once they back out of the first Activity on the stack you could implement the "press back again to exit app" option and then destory it on the second 'back' click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean killing an application screen progrmatically use -

finish();

once you leave the activity for another screen, if you mean physically (using the device physical buttons) than a long push on the home button will show you all the apps running on the foreground swipe them to the left or to the right in order to terminate them
*However* some apps uses services in order to fetch data or make logic operations which are unbound to the UI for those you should go to the "Application manager" on your device setting and kill them manually (by pressing stop) you can also use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.taskmanager) app.